# How to add double click event on a table row using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
var nextRow = tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length;
var row = tbl.tBodies[0].insertRow(nextRow);
row.setAttribute('ondblclick', "return move_to_x_graph();");
```

This code will add a double click  event on a row.
But the thing is it's not working in case of  Internet Explorer.It's working fine in case of  all the other browsers.

For adding style I am handling this:

```
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var browser = navigator.appName;
if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    cell2.style.setAttribute("cssText", "color:black; width:300px;");
} else {
    cell2.setAttribute("style", "color:black; width:300px;");
}
```

Can anybody help me to add double click event using  Javascript that will also work in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't set event handlers using `setAttribute`, it doesn't work as you'd expect in IE. Instead set it directly on the equivalent event handler property of the element:

```
row.ondblclick = function() {
    return move_to_x_graph();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
$(row).bind("dblclick", function(){return move_to_x_graph();});
```

Also, maybe you can add it to the cells instead of the row:

```
$(row).find("td").bind("dblclick", function(){return move_to_x_graph();});
```

If you are not using jquery, give it a try, it makes things easier.  Or any other framework like Prototype or so.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a string argument. Try passing a function literal like this:

```
row.setAttribute('ondblclick', function () {return move_to_x_graph();});
```